# Compute gradient vector field of an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to read in an image - a picture of a circle, and compute the gradient vector field of that image (ie vectors pointing out uniformly and at normal to the circle). My logic is failing me a bit, but I have:

```
clear all;
im = im2double(imread('littlecircle.png'));
im = double(im);
[nr,nc]=size(im);
[dx,dy] = gradient(im);
[x y] = meshgrid(1:nc,1:nr);
u = x;
v = y;
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

if I were to simply do the above, I get a vector field, but it is simply the gradient of an empty mesh (ie just a vector field of the gradient y=x). What I actually want is to use

```
[dx,dy] = gradient(im);
```

to detect the edges of the circle in the image, and then compute the gradient vector field due to the circle in the image. obviously, assigning u=x and v=y will only give me the vector field of a straight line - so bascially, I want to embed the gradient of the image into the vectors u and v. How do I do this?

[image: my result]

[image: image that i am getting error with]

Comment: Can you post littlecircle.png?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have made a mistake in the code (other than that, it works fine). You should replace the following:

```
u = dx;
v = dy;
```

not

```
u = x;
v = y;
```

It works with [this](http://altreligion.about.com/od/symbols/ig/Geometric-Shapes/Circles.htm) image like a charm!

EDIT:
If you want to super-impose the vectors on the image, then do the following:

```
clear all;
im = imread('littlecircle.png');
[nr,nc]=size(im);
[dx,dy] = gradient(double(im));
[x y] = meshgrid(1:nc,1:nr);
u = dx;
v = dy;
imshow(im);
hold on
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

Notice that i do not convert the im to double, since it would not appear correctly with imshow (needs uint8). Depending on your image dimensions, you might want to zoom in in order to see the grad vectors.

You can see a zoomed in area of the vectors superimposed on the image, below:

[image: Gradient vectors of a circle in an image]

Better quality image is at https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQbwI.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However I think I have not explained the problem thoroughly enough. the gradient vectors that are produced in my code, and also your code are not the gradient vectors caused by the circle in the image. The gradient field produced should be pointing outwards and at normal to the circle. so you see i do not simply want to have u = x, but rather u = the gradient of the image domain in the x direction.

Comment: if you run this code

    clear all;
    im = imread('littlecircle.png');
    im = im(:,:,1);
    im = double(im);
    [nr,nc]=size(im);
    [dx,dy] = gradient(im);
    quiver(dx,dy);

on any image you like, you will see what I am after (look at what the quiver plot looks like). although here I am simply returning a quiverplot of a scalar field. I would like to however return the actual vector field and use the vector field later in my program.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. In the code i posted the vectors *do* point outwards from the circle (i attached a zoomed in screenshot). Of course, since you have a computational routine that computes the grad in a discrete space (image) the vectors cannot be absolutely normal to the circle due to quantization i.e. don't expect to see "perfect" grad vectors as if computed analytically for a given mathematical circle.

Comment: Another note regarding the vector field. gradient(im) does return a *vector field*. For example in [dx,dy] = gradient(im) dx and dy are matrices with the same dimensions as im. For example if im is 200x300 then so are dx,dy. These represent the x and y components of the grad vectors at each point. Thus, for the point (123,245) in the image, the gradient vector there is v=[dx(123,245),dy(123,245)]; Of course, since you want to use a vector **field** you will also need the coordinates of the base space i.e. the x,y matrices.

Comment: thanks Jorge - I got there in the end thanks to your help. the way matlab uses vectors has always confused me. your explanation has helped a lot!

Comment: one thing - if I use a different image the one you have a created - a 101x101 .png in my case I get the following error: ??? Error using ==> quiver at 58
The size of X must match the size of U or the number of columns of U. why is this? I haven't changed the code from yours whatsoever....

Comment: This error seems to imply that the x,y matrices don't have the same dimensions as the u,v matrices. Maybe the meshgrid code returns a wrong grid? If you can upload you image i could test it.

Comment: i will upload the image into my previous post as I cannot answer my own question yet!

Comment: i don't seem to be able to upload it. all i did was draw a circle in paint size 101x101. how do i upload the actual file for you to test?

Comment: you can upload it to some image hosting site and paste the link here. Google docs maybe?

Comment: good idea here is the link https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iDswLYaZ0zSUVaa1N4aUNtMzg/edit

Comment: I don't have permissions to access it. Can you make it public?

Comment: yes just made it public https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0iDswLYaZ0zSUVaa1N4aUNtMzg

Comment: Ok i see the problem. The image you posted is rgb, whereas the code works with grayscale images only. Thus you should convert it using: im=rgb2gray(imread('littlecircle.png')), and it works fine.

Comment: @Jorge Can you explain your previous comment. I want to solve the same problem. The comment is:

gradient(im) does return a vector field. For example in [dx,dy] = gradient(im) dx and dy are matrices with the same dimensions as im. For example if im is 200x300 then so are dx,dy. These represent the x and y components of the grad vectors at each point. Thus, for the point (123,245) in the image, the gradient vector there is v=[dx(123,245),dy(123,245)]; Of course, since you want to use a vector field you will also need the coordinates of the base space i.e. the x,y matrices.