# Image Gradient Vector Field in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy, gradient

I am trying to get the [Gradient Vector Field](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/Gradient2.svg/566px-Gradient2.svg.png) of an image using Python (similar to [this matlab question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416918/compute-gradient-vector-field-of-an-image)).

This is the original image:
[image: http:/ /dcc.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~rbaravalle/gradient/test.png]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

I = Image.open('test.png').transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
I = I.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
p = np.asarray(I)
w,h = I.size
y, x = np.mgrid[0:h:500j, 0:w:500j]

dy, dx = np.gradient(p)
skip = (slice(None, None, 3), slice(None, None, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(I, extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
ax.quiver(x[skip], y[skip], dx[skip], dy[skip])

ax.set(aspect=1, title='Quiver Plot')
plt.show()
```

This is the result:
[image: http://dcc.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~rbaravalle/gradient/result.png]

The problem is that the vectors seem to be incorrect. This point gets more clear when you zoom in the image:

[image: http://dcc.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~rbaravalle/gradient/result2.png]

Why do some of the vectors point to the center as expected, while others do not?

Maybe there is an issue with the result of the call to `np.gradient`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your strange results are, at least in part, because p is of type `uint8`. Even numpy diff results in clearly incorrect values for an array of this dtype. If you convert to signed integer by replacing the definition of `p` with the following: `p = np.asarray(I).astype(int8)` then the results of diff are correct. The following code gives me what looks like a reasonable field,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

I = Image.open('./test.png')
I = I.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
p = np.asarray(I).astype('int8')
w,h = I.size
x, y = np.mgrid[0:h:500j, 0:w:500j]

dy, dx = np.gradient(p)
skip = (slice(None, None, 3), slice(None, None, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(I.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM), 
               extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.colorbar(im)
ax.quiver(x[skip], y[skip], dx[skip].T, dy[skip].T)

ax.set(aspect=1, title='Quiver Plot')
plt.show()
```

This gives the following:

[image: Solution]

and close up this looks like you'd expect,

[image]

Comment: Great catch, `.astype('int8')` works just as well. It's the `u` (unsigned) that's creating problems with negative gradients (clipping negative values to positive values)

Comment: It's the solution, thank you very much!.Actually, I moved the "transpose" call to im = ax.imshow(I), i.e.im = ax.imshow(I.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)), and then i got the exactly same result as your image. If you want, change it so people can use your code directly.
Also, I agree that using np.int8 is probably better than float.

Comment: Update: A "softer" version can be obtained using a gaussian filter on the gradients. i.e.: http://dcc.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~rbaravalle/gradient/resultSoft.png
The code results: http://dcc.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~rbaravalle/gradient/test3.py

Comment: The use of unsigned integer in numpy routines like diff/gradient seems like a bit of a gotcha. As suggested I've moved transpose into the imshow, changed to int8 and remove the minus from dy.